# NiFi generating huge log file - continuously logging - A flow controller execution task has been cancelled

Tags: logging, apache-nifi

My Nifi instance is furiously generating huge amount of same log over and over again. My flow consists of ExecuteStreamCommand which is calling a Java excutable jar internally. Also, look at the NiFi UI, that processor seems to be stuck with 1 Active Thread. Even when I restart NiFi, it seems that this state is preserved and it continues to happen. As you can see below it's logging thousands of lines of same log within a second. Crazy!

```
    016-08-03 17:21:12,904 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@3fe940f' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,904 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5c02799' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@52871b90' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5c488f85' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2be136ef' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2f1930e5' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4528e50d' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5d046e8a' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7ff06d8b' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@1908e488' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@1b8a6a29' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,915 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@650437ec' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@196492f2' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@471609f2' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@f05e81b' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4bfa0540' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@76b4fdcf' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@19a2372' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@21ff466a' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@3ab48710' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6bbf5f0c' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:12,926 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@3b6e60ba' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,131 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@60f9bdab' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,131 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7eeb3aa3' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,131 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6f3d5d4d' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,131 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@271e8ba0' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,131 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@aa77e0d' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,132 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2d3e73d8' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,132 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@286c9407' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,132 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7bfc4921' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,132 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4a1a0745' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,132 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@14640d6d' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@58646f4a' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@41488026' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5b728765' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6f49e603' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@14acca9f' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@11e0219c' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5e66d56a' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7e3f595b' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@c359c31' has been cancelled.
2016-08-03 17:21:13,142 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@1c49a0ea' has been cancelled.
```

Comment: Did you turn on debug logging? It looks like org.apache.nifi is logging at the debug level which would explain why you are seeing so many logs. By default the logback.xml that comes with NiFi logs at the INFO level.

Comment: That was it. I should have been more clear with the question though. Why does Nifi log this statement so furiously? Is it because my processors are marked with a schedule value of 0 so it's running and cancelling the task every certain milli second? Looks like it has to do something with nifi property nifi.bored.yield.duration=xx. I 'll change it to a higher value and verify. btw, how do I mark the answer? dont see an option.

Comment: I'll write it as an answer rather then a comment so you can mark/vote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like org.apache.nifi is logging at the debug level which would explain why you are seeing so many logs. By default the logback.xml that comes with NiFi logs at the INFO level.

The FlowEngine is a thread pool executor that executes all of the tasks for the flow, and the logging statement you are seeing happens when checking the result of a task completing. You are correct that when a processor is schedule to run at 0 seconds it is executing as fast as possible which does execute a lot of tasks. I'm not totally sure why so many tasks are reporting as cancelled vs. regular completion.